# working of SAMPLE with replacement function

Tags: sql, teradata

I know the concept of SAMPLE and SAMPLE WITH REPLACEMENT. But I can't wrap my head around the below: Below is the data in my table.

```
The stores table contains the following data:
store_id city state
----------- ------------------------- -----
1 Big Sur CA
2 Monterey CA
3 Napa CA
4 Oceanside CA
5 Rancho Bernardo CA
6 Sonoma CA
7 Algiers Point LA
8 New Orleans LA
9 Charlotte NC
10 North Wilkesboro NC
11 Midway UT
12 Moab UT
13 Park City UT
14 Springdale UT
15 Charleston WV
16 White Sulfur Springs WV
```

Now when I run the below query I get 24 rows:

```
SELECT city
,state
,SAMPLEID
FROM stores
SAMPLE WITH REPLACEMENT
WHEN state = 'UT' THEN 4, 2
WHEN state = 'WV' THEN 2, 1
ELSE 10, 5 END ORDER BY 3;
```

What does the 2 indicate in `WHEN state = 'UT' THEN 4, 2`
What does the 1 indicate in `WHEN state = 'WV' THEN 2, 1`
What does 5 indicate n `ELSE 10, 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers indicate multiple samples, in your case for each WHEN there are two samples returned:

(4 + 2) + (2 + 1) + (10 + 5) = 24 rows

You can request up to 16 (iirc) samples for each WHEN.

Add SAMPLEID to the column list to see which row is returned by which sample.

Comment: Yes, there is Sample ID there and yes I noticed this for eg for UT there are 4 samples from ID 1 and 2 from ID 2, and similarly for others..